# Spring Boot redirect to a landing page then onto an endpoint

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a landing page success.html, where after a successful change of password, they land on this page, to be told their change of password was successful, from there, after pressing the continue button on that page, they go to the '/home' endpoint. On the backend, the mapping for this is:-

```
       model.clear();
       model.setViewName("redirect:/home");
       
       return model;
```

My question is how do I redirect to my success.html page with the success message, I have tried:

```
model.setViewName("redirect:/success.html");
```

Since I haven't created an endpoint for success, I just want this just to be a temporary landing page, then press continue, and stay on the changePassword endpoint '/changePassword'.

Thanks for any help